# How to discard JSON elements with specific values while deserializing

Tags: c#, json.net

This is an interesting situation. My application saves and loads JSON data from MongoDB, which works fine 95% of the time. The JSON data in such cases is like the following:

```
{
    "isDemo": true,
    "CustomerReference": "nabTest",
    "Fee": null,
    "OrderId": "48/XYZ3",   
    "Asynchronous": false,
}
```

The remaining 5% of the time,a legacy application loads some XML data, converts that into JSON format and inserts that into the same MongoDB collection. The JSON data in such cases is like this:

```
{
   "@xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
   "@xmlns:xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
   "@xmlns":"http://MyDomain.com.au/SomeService.Contract/2007/06/18",
   "isDemo":{
      "@xmlns":"http://MyDomain.com.au/ABC.Services",
      "#text":"true"
   },
   "Asynchronous":{
      "@xmlns":"http://MyDomain.com.au/ABC.Services"
      "#text":"false"
   },
   "Fee":{
      "@xsi:nil":"true",
      "@xmlns":"http://MyDomain.com.au/ABC.Services"
   },
   "CustomerReference":{
      "@xmlns":"http://MyDomain.com.au/ABC.Services"      
   },
   "OrderId":"48/XYZ3"
}
```

In such cases, Newtonsoft deserializer crashes with the following exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered
> while parsing value: {. Path 'CustomerReference', line 1, position
> 919.'

The minimum code for this is the following:

```
// 'result' is of type object, loaded from MongoDB
var resultStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultStr, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

What is an elegant way to handle this situation, with minimal code changes.

Comment: The most elegant way to handle this is make sure you are not putting all the xml namespaces into the json, if you cant do that, you will likely need to write a converter and filter out all the gunk

Comment: none of the Json tell us what type is Fee. Would you mind giving the object representation of the first Json.

Answer (score 1):

Your Object representation for the normal Json should be something like this :

```
using J = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute; 
public partial class Data
{
       [J("isDemo")]            public bool? IsDemo { get; set; }             
       [J("Asynchronous")]      public bool? IsAsynchronous { get; set; }    
         
       [J("OrderId")]           public string OrderId { get; set; }          
       [J("CustomerReference")] public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
       [J("Fee")]               public double? Fee { get; set; }              
}
```

While having a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) handeling the whole Xml representation will be nice. I find it difficult to write and maintain.
You should divide and conquer:

- Generate a class that is the representation of the Xml-ish Json.
- Remove unnecessary property, keep Xml "nil" where needed
- Create simple custom converter for mapping string representation to the correct type.
  eg: "true" => bool, "123" => int,

```
public partial class XmlRepresentation
{                        
  [J("isDemo")]            public BoolWrapper IsDemo { get; set; }                
  [J("Asynchronous")]      public BoolWrapper Asynchronous { get; set; }          
  [J("Fee")]               public DoubleWrapper Fee { get; set; }                            
  [J("CustomerReference")] public StringWrapper CustomerReference { get; set; }
  [J("OrderId")]           public string OrderId { get; set; }                     
}

public partial class NullableXmlValue
{   
  [J("@xsi:nil")][JsonConverter(typeof(BoolParseStringConverter))] 
  public bool IsNull { get; set; }
}
public partial class BoolWrapper :NullableXmlValue
{
  [J("#text")][JsonConverter(typeof(BoolParseStringConverter))] 
  public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public partial class StringWrapper :NullableXmlValue
{
  [J("#text")] public string Value { get; set; }
}

public partial class DoubleWrapper :NullableXmlValue
{
  [J("#text")][JsonConverter(typeof(DoubleParseStringConverter))] 
  public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

With some simple String to Type {Bool, Double} parser:

```
internal class BoolParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
   public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(bool) || t == typeof(bool?);

   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
      var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
      if (Boolean.TryParse(value, out bool b))
      {
         return b;
      }
      throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type bool");
   }

   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      if (untypedValue == null)
      {
         serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
         return;
      }
      var value = (bool)untypedValue;
      var boolString = value ? "true" : "false";
      serializer.Serialize(writer, boolString);
      return;
   }

   public static readonly BoolParseStringConverter Singleton = new BoolParseStringConverter();
}

internal class DoubleParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
   public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(double) || t == typeof(double?);

   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
      var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
      if (Double.TryParse(value, out double l))
      {
         return l;
      }
      throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
   }

   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      if (untypedValue == null)
      {
         serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
         return;
      }
      var value = (double)untypedValue;
      serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
      return;
   }

   public static readonly DoubleParseStringConverter Singleton = new DoubleParseStringConverter();
}
```

This way you can directly deserialize  to `XmlRepresentation` and use a simple projection logic to get the Data.

```
public partial class XmlRepresentation
{  
   public Data ToDataType(){
      var result = new Data();
      if( !this.IsDemo?.IsNull ?? false)
         result.IsDemo = this.IsDemo.Value;

       // etc..

       return result;
   }
}
```

And for knowing if it's the normal Json or the Xml-ish one I will simply use a try catch.
That way I won't have to write complexe `JsonConverter` or class that represent both Normal and Xml-ish.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I saw and tested your proposed solution, before writing this.Reading the doc it should have work just fine. But my naive attempt was a failure https://dotnetfiddle.net/jodh7c. So I thought about what if it's simply not valid Xml for what ever reason. And came up with this. But I didn't play to mutch with `` `DeserializeXmlNode` and cannot tell if the Xml is bad or broken. I understand that it's a lot of code and can be see as complexe. For example all the converter can be removed and we map every thing to string only to convert it in the `ToDataType()`

Comment: @CodeCaster, I would argue that it was still a good answer for anyone that get real Xml as Json.

Answer (score -1):

Please use like this in Model:

```cs
public class User
{
    // always require a string value
    [JsonProperty("name", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // don't require any value
    [JsonProperty("role", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    // property is ignored
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Result generated with Json.NET serialization attributes:

```json
{
"type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "role": {
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "name"
    ]
}
```